# How do I sort the result from SQL JOIN's? (Groupwise max?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some issues with this query. What I want to do is select specific information about my users, but also include the latest dates of their latest campaign, and latest invoice.

I'm currently getting results returned, but the invoice and campaign data is not sorted by date.

```
SELECT cu.uid, cu.email, cu.company, cu.phone, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, cu.city, cu.crdate,     sc.crdate, invoice.total
FROM  `corp_users` cu
LEFT JOIN sponsored_campaigns AS sc ON cu.uid=sc.userid 
LEFT JOIN corp_invoices AS invoice ON cu.uid=invoice.userid
WHERE cu.company != ""
GROUP BY cu.uid
ORDER BY cu.crdate DESC
```

I've read this resource (http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/groupwise-max/) about groupwise-max, but I'm not able to get it to work properly. After following the steps by code looks like this, and in the return rows it always display NULL on the dates of the users.

```
SELECT cu.uid, cu.email, cu.company, cu.phone, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, cu.city, cu.crdate, sc.crdate, invoice.total
FROM  `corp_users` cu

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT a.uid, MAX(b.crdate) MaxInvoice, MAX(c.crdate) MaxCampaign FROM corp_users a 
LEFT JOIN corp_invoices b ON a.uid=b.userid 
LEFT JOIN sponsored_campaigns c ON a.uid=b.userid 
GROUP BY a.uid
) temp ON cu.uid=temp.uid

LEFT JOIN sponsored_campaigns AS sc ON cu.uid=sc.userid AND sc.crdate=temp.MaxCampaign
LEFT JOIN corp_invoices AS invoice ON cu.uid=invoice.userid AND invoice.crdate=temp.MaxInvoice
WHERE cu.company != ""
GROUP BY cu.uid
ORDER BY cu.crdate DESC
```

To summarize my question. How do I return the result where sc.crdate and invoice.crdate is the latest of each table.?

Comment: what's your question?  How to sort fields that have a null field?

Comment: I want to know how I fetch invoice.crdate and sc.crdate as the LATEST entries in those tables. Basically I want the latest invoice and the latest campaign. 

Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: try this `ORDER BY COALESCE(invoice.crdate, sc.crdate), cu.crdate DESC` -> you should show a sample output and how you want it sorted